# Chrome automatically formats Error stacks, how does this work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

The content of `(new Error('foo')).stack` looks something like this:

```
Error: foo
    at Object.notifier (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:12705:37)
    at trackHookChanges (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:1813:27)
    at UseState (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:1982:13)
    at K._.data (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:70174:6005)
    at K (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:70174:6380)
    at Z (http://localhost:6969/js/main.js:70174:9187)
```

However, when I `console.log` it, it looks like:

```
Error: foo
    at Object.notifier (wdyr.ts:10)
    at trackHookChanges (whyDidYouRender.js:1306)
    at UseState (whyDidYouRender.js:1475)
    at K._.data (index.esm.js:1)
    at K (index.esm.js:1)
    at Z (index.esm.js:1)
```

Is Chrome devtools is using sourcemaps to automatically change the string being logged? Is it there an easy way to access the source file names in my code? I want to ignore errors originating from certain NPM module.

Comment: why not catching those errors in the first place?

Comment: I'm not throwing the error, just using it to get the stacktrace

Comment: yes but if i understand correctly, the error is thrown by some functions of some third party npm module, and if you do not care about those errors, you can catch them around the function call

Comment: No, the package `welldone-software/why-did-you-render` calls my callback when React state changes, I want to know if the state change came from specific 3rd party hooks. I need a way to know if the 3rd party hook is in the call stack

Comment: I do not know what the answer is to your question, but this source may help: https://web.archive.org/web/20140210004225/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699850.aspx

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339551/stack-traces-that-utilise-source-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately *(but luckly for devs)* yes, Chrome uses sourcemaps to format errors in the console and there is (still) no way to access the same function it uses or output it produces. Even if it was possible, it would work only on a specific browser/platform.

### TLDR

Emulate the browser sourcemap resolution with [StackTraceJS](https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!) or filter your errors by their prototype or any of their properties (like `Error.message` for example)

### Discussion

JS Errors stacktrace are a mess, and so unreliable:

- they are very dependant on the running environment, if you run code on Chrome you could end up with a different stack with respect of running it on Firefox, IE or node (even if in the latest times they are reaching to a *"stacktrace agreement"* between environments).
- The maximum length of the error stacktrace is (almost always) 10 lines, so if your function (hook) was called before that time you will never catch it.
- internal or delayed callbacks can erase/change/augment the stacktrace of a function in certain environments (it can be very hard, sometimes impossible, to catch the full stacktrace of a callback called inside a `setTimeout` for example)

### Partial solution (StackTraceJS)

If you can afford to make a http request for a sourcemap, you can exploit the same mechanism that Chrome (or any other browser) uses to parse and map the error stacktrace files into the original files and filter those you don't like. The downside of this operation is that your code must be completely reworked with promise-like chain (because of the http request).

Luckly there is already a library which makes this process much much easier: [StackTraceJS](https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!), you can give it a try.

This would be its usage (from library docs):

```
var error = new Error('BOOM!');
StackTrace.fromError(error).then(callback).catch(errback)
/*
==> Promise([
    {functionName: 'fn', fileName: 'file.js', lineNumber: 32, columnNumber: 1},
    {functionName: 'fn2', fileName: 'file.js', lineNumber: 543, columnNumber: 32},
    {functionName: 'fn3', fileName: 'file.js', lineNumber: 8, columnNumber: 1}
], Error)
*/
```

##### Side Note

As you stated in the question comment, you are using React, and the usual working pipeline is using wepack or other js bundler to output a single JS file from all the dependencies. During developing you could encounter no problems to find out the file from the errors stack, but in production you could omit sourcemap informations from the bundle or either have some internal/uglified filenames which are not linked with the original file. This means that the behaviour of your code could change between dev/prod configuration depending on your building pipeline.

### Theoretical solution

The (proto-OOP) theory states to use prototype to discriminate between Error types in order to filter unwanted behaviours.

- So first of all you ***should*** use a custom class to define the errors thrown by your application/library (see [Custom Error - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/error#custom_error_types) section). By doing so you ***must*** throw or extend only your CustomError(s) in your code.
- Secondly you ***should*** filter the error by its type/properties and not by its source file, so (if you can) check what classes of Error the 3rd party function can throw.

In this way it's easy to isolate only those 3rd party errors, you can do just a simple check of inheritance within the `try/catch` block:

```
try { /* dangerous code */ }
catch (ex) {
    if (ex instanceof MyError) { /* handle your errors */ }
    else if (ex instanceof The3rdPartyCustomError) { /* handle specific 3rd party CustomError */ }
    else if (ex.__proto__ instanceof Error) { /* handle generic 3rd party CustomErrors */ }
    else { /* handle native errors (or bad practice 3rd party errors) */ }
}
```

But all of this theory can be difficult to implement, especially because 3rd party libraries very rarely implement their CustomError classes, so you will end up to handle only native errors and your defined classes.

Give it a try and check what kind of errors can throw your 3rd parties libs.
Maybe the simpler solution is to filter the erros by `Error.message` or any other properties which could work better than expected in your domain case.